# Argument of type '{ value: any; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Angular app that has a feature where you can see you past orders and repeat a purchase of a past order.
What I am trying to do is to store the products of the order in a new array and send it over API using POST method. But I keep gettign this error:

```
Argument of type '{ value: any; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ sifra: string; naziv: string; kolicina: number; ean: string; em: string; cena: number; rabat1: number; rabat2: number; prednarocilo: number; ismail: number; }[]'.
[ng]   Type '{ value: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ sifra: string; naziv: string; kolicina: number; ean: string; em: string; cena: number; rabat1: number; rabat2: number; prednarocilo: number; ismail: number; }': sifra, naziv, kolicina, ean, and 6 more.
[ng] 
[ng] 62     this.cartService.repeatOrder(products).subscribe(
```

Here is my code if anyone can help me solve this issue.

**single-order.ts:**

```
export interface SingleOrder {
  id: number;
  datum: string;
  datum_dobave: string;
  dostava: number;
  g_popust: number;
  opomba: string;
  predkoci1narocilo: number;
  kc: number;
  prevoznik: string;
  narocilnica: string;
  narocilnicadate: string;
  izdelki: {
    sifra: string;
    naziv: string;
    kolicina: number;
    ean: string;
    em: string;
    cena: number;
    rabat1: number;
    rabat2: number;
    prednarocilo: number;
    ismail: number;
  }[];
}
```

**cart.service.ts:**

```
  repeatOrder(products: SingleOrder['izdelki']) {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        const formData: any = new FormData();
        formData.append('products', products);
        return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}cart/repeatorder`, formData, {headers, observe: 'response'});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log('Error 400: ', err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  };
```

**order-view.page.ts:**

```
export class Izdelki {
  sifra: string;
  naziv: string;
  kolicina: number;
  ean: string;
  em: string;
  cena: number;
  rabat1: number;
  rabat2: number;
  prednarocilo: number;
  ismail: number;
}

      order: SingleOrder;
      orderProducts: SingleOrder['izdelki'];
      repeatOrderArr: Izdelki[];
    
      repeatThisPurchase() {
        this.repeatOrderArr= [...this.orderProducts];
    
        const products = Object.keys(this.repeatOrderArr).map(key => ({value: this.repeatOrderArr[key]}));
    
        console.log(products);
    
        this.cartService.repeatOrder(products).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log('Data sent to cart: ', data);
          },
          error => {
            console.log('Error', error);
          }
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const products = Object.keys(this.repeatOrderArr).map(key => ({value: this.repeatOrderArr[key]}));
```

this line of code is incorrect or unnecessary. You are looping over the keys of an array (strange) and for each you are creating an object with a value property set as the element at the specific index(strange as well)

Try passing `this.repeatOrderArr` to the function.

```
this.cartService.repeatOrder(this.repeatOrderArr).subscribe(
```

Comment: I have done what you wrote and I get an error 500 and the payload of my API call is just this: products: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: That depends on what your api is expecting. Are you sure you have to use a formdata in your http request?

Comment: No I’m not sure

Comment: What can I use instead? Should I make the code for API call different?

Comment: @weinde, that depends entirely on what your API is expecting. And whatever format it is expecting, you have to serialize your data to match (i.e., you cannot just append an array of Objects to `FormData`, which expects a string and would convert each object to `[object Object]`).

Answer (score 1):

the map function on order-view.ts is casting your Izdelki array to {value: Izdelki}[] and as you show in the code, the method repeatOrder requires a Izdelki instance as parameter... What you're expecting with this .map() function?

Comment: COuld you provide a code example please? I dont understand your answer. Wherre should I provide Izdelki instace?

Comment: In repeatOrder(products: SingleOrder['izdelki']) method the signature is asking for an model as the model 'izdelki' defined as a property of SingleOrder... in the map function you're casting each izdelki instance into a {value: Izdelki} array